# set include_path for embed files like .js and .css?

Tags: php, javascript, css, include-path

OK so I now know there is a way to put all my php files in a single place and have them be able to be included without a filepath by setting an include_path like so:

```
php_value include_path .:/pathToPHPFiles
```

OK so now as long as my PHP files are in this directory I can include them from any subdirectory as if they were in the same directory.

I am wondering if there is a trick like this for other file types like .css and .js so I can put them all in single location and embed them in a page without worring about the filepath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
define("CSSPATH", "/path/to/css/");

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.CSSPATH.'style.css" />';
```

or, in a `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^(.*\.css)$ path/to/css/$1
```

I'm not sure about the .htaccess version... corrections welcome.

Comment: This looks like a nice way to do what I want. I haven't tried it out yet but I will. Just a note though: regex starts at $1 not $0. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the `base` tag.

```
...
<head>
    <base href="/somepath/">
    ...
</head>
<body>
<!-- the following images src  will be resolved into '/somepath/image.png'
<img src="image.png" alt=""/> 
...
```

But then again, why not just use absolute urls, that is, urls beginning with `/` ?